# Telegram Bot Null Pointer Exception when executing Firestore methods

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, telegram-bot

I am currently trying to validate user text submissions by querying them in Firestore first before sending them a reply. This is done using Firebase Admin SDK and https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots. Problem is that when accessing the methods that interact with Firestore (verifyValidUserAndOrganisation), the method doesn't execute yet the object is not null when I checked in debugger.

I am not sure what is the error and if there is, please suggest any other ways to validate with an asynchronous Firestore database read.

Function in question:

```
@NotNull
private Predicate<Update> validUserAndOrganisation() {
    return upd -> {
        String message = upd.getMessage().getText().trim();
        // Need to check both user telegram id and organisation code valid
        // Then proceed with allowing next reply, else need to throw message and stop ability
        if (message.length() == 6) { // Only proceed if length of text is valid for an org. code
            if (isValidOrganisationCode(message)) { // Additional check for text being valid organisation code regex to reduce unnecessary Firestore reads.
                // Check firebase
                try {
                    Verification verification = firebaseDB.verifyValidUserAndOrganisation(upd.getChatMember().getFrom().getId(), message); // <---- Here
                    if (verification.getSuccess()) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        silent.send(verification.getReason(), getChatId(upd)); // Will submit false afterwards to signify failing the check
                        return false;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else if (message.length() > 0 && !message.equals("/submit")) {
            silent.send("Please enter a valid organisation code", getChatId(upd));
        }
        return false;
    };
}
```

Error logs:

```
[MyCelsiusBot Telegram Executor] INFO org.telegram.abilitybots.api.bot.BaseAbilityBot - [MyCelsiusBot] New update [41791280] received at 2022-02-07T00:31:52.469791300+08:00[Asia/Singapore]
[MyCelsiusBot Telegram Executor] INFO org.telegram.abilitybots.api.bot.BaseAbilityBot - Update(updateId=41791280, message=Message(messageId=163, from=User(id=5003829958, firstName=Kez, isBot=false, lastName=null, userName=Kzeezee, languageCode=en, canJoinGroups=null, canReadAllGroupMessages=null, supportInlineQueries=null), date=1644165113, chat=Chat(id=5003829958, type=private, title=null, firstName=Kez, lastName=null, userName=Kzeezee, allMembersAreAdministrators=null, photo=null, description=null, inviteLink=null, pinnedMessage=null, stickerSetName=null, canSetStickerSet=null, permissions=null, slowModeDelay=null, bio=null, linkedChatId=null, location=null, messageAutoDeleteTime=null, allowSavingContent=null, hasPrivateForwards=null), forwardFrom=null, forwardFromChat=null, forwardDate=null, text=Hhhhhh, entities=null, captionEntities=null, audio=null, document=null, photo=null, sticker=null, video=null, contact=null, location=null, venue=null, animation=null, pinnedMessage=null, newChatMembers=[], leftChatMember=null, newChatTitle=null, newChatPhoto=null, deleteChatPhoto=null, groupchatCreated=null, replyToMessage=null, voice=null, caption=null, superGroupCreated=null, channelChatCreated=null, migrateToChatId=null, migrateFromChatId=null, editDate=null, game=null, forwardFromMessageId=null, invoice=null, successfulPayment=null, videoNote=null, authorSignature=null, forwardSignature=null, mediaGroupId=null, connectedWebsite=null, passportData=null, forwardSenderName=null, poll=null, replyMarkup=null, dice=null, viaBot=null, senderChat=null, proximityAlertTriggered=null, messageAutoDeleteTimerChanged=null, voiceChatStarted=null, voiceChatEnded=null, voiceChatParticipantsInvited=null, voiceChatScheduled=null, isAutomaticForward=null, canBeForwarded=null), inlineQuery=null, chosenInlineQuery=null, callbackQuery=null, editedMessage=null, channelPost=null, editedChannelPost=null, shippingQuery=null, preCheckoutQuery=null, poll=null, pollAnswer=null, myChatMember=null, chatMember=null, chatJoinRequest=null)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at bot.MyCelsiusTelegramBot.lambda$validUserAndOrganisation$12(MyCelsiusTelegramBot.java:145)
    at org.telegram.abilitybots.api.objects.Reply.lambda$isOkFor$1(Reply.java:97)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$1ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.reduce(ReferencePipeline.java:563)
    at org.telegram.abilitybots.api.objects.Reply.isOkFor(Reply.java:98)
    at org.telegram.abilitybots.api.bot.BaseAbilityBot.lambda$filterReply$22(BaseAbilityBot.java:663)
    at org.telegram.abilitybots.api.bot.BaseAbilityBot.runSilently(BaseAbilityBot.java:674)
    at org.telegram.abilitybots.api.bot.BaseAbilityBot.lambda$filterReply$23(BaseAbilityBot.java:663)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:176)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.reduce(ReferencePipeline.java:553)
    at org.telegram.abilitybots.api.bot.BaseAbilityBot.filterReply(BaseAbilityBot.java:669)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:176)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$StreamBuilderImpl.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:411)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.telegram.abilitybots.api.bot.BaseAbilityBot.onUpdateReceived(BaseAbilityBot.java:234)
    at org.telegram.abilitybots.api.bot.AbilityBot.onUpdateReceived(AbilityBot.java:55)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:317)
[MyCelsiusBot Telegram Executor] INFO org.telegram.abilitybots.api.bot.BaseAbilityBot - [MyCelsiusBot] Processing of update [41791280] ended at 2022-02-07T00:31:52.547348100+08:00[Asia/Singapore]
---> Processing time: [77 ms] <---
```

I also have the entire project at https://github.com/Kzeezee/MyCelsius if information is insufficient.

Comment: Which line is line 145? Is it the one with the `// <---- Here` comment on it? Also, please don't link to resources outside Stack Overflow as they can break over time. (In fact, it seems your link has already broken: I get a 404 error for it.)

Comment: @LukeWoodward Yes its this specific line. `Verification verification = firebaseDB.verifyValidUserAndOrganisation(upd.getChatMember().getFrom().getId(), message); // <---- Here`. Also apologies, I have corrected the link.

Comment: You write in your question that "the object is not null": which object? You could get an NPE from line 145 if any of `firebaseDB`, `upd`, `upd.getChatMember()`, `upd.getChatMember().getFrom()` or `upd.getChatMember().getFrom().getId()` are `null`. Evidently one of them is, you will need to find out which one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @LukeWoodward, I did find my mistake and that `upd.getChatMember()` was the one responsible for giving me the null pointer exception.

`upd.getChatMember()` will be null if the messages are coming from direct DMs in Telegram and not from group chats. For that, you need to use `upd.getMessage().getFrom().getId()` for getting the user's id who direct messaged your bot.